# fix no unnecessary generics

Tags: typescript, generics, tslint

So I just tried to make a pull request on GitHub where I added generics to a method call. The method passes it to an interface which then determines the return type of its methods.

Now the linter started complaining:

```
ERROR: 65:105  no-unnecessary-generics  Type parameter ResultT is used only once.
```

Which is this line:

```
executeSql<ResultT = any>(sqlStatement: string, arguments?: any[]): Promise<[Transaction, ResultSet<ResultT>]>;
```

And here is the interface:

```
export interface ResultSetRowList<ResultT> {
    length: number;
    raw(): ResultT[];
    item(index: number): ResultT;
}
```

So I don't think that it is a `no-unnecessary-generics` matter, or is it?

There is the pull [request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/40864)

Comment: Why do you precise the definition of `ResultSetRowList`?

Comment: Because it's a database query and it would be nice to tell typescript what the return structure is.

Answer (score 1):

The "no-unnecessary-generics" happens when a generic argument is used only once like

```
const foo = <T>(x: T) => ....
// as it is literally same as
const foo = (x: any) => ....
```

When the generic is used at least twice

```
const foo = <T>(x: T): T => ....
```

It will work.

I find this rule unnecessary. It might be wiser to turn it off as it cannot see "inside" of interfaces to check the usage. Thus it can see usage once as a generic argument of the interface as false positive.

The main idea of the rule is to prevent this

```
const foo = <T extends SomeType>(x: T) => ...
```

as it's literally the same as writing

```
const foo = (x: SomeType) => .... // and this is good practice
```

In both cases you are assigning variable that inherits/implements SomeType or is SomeType. In first case you are actually choosing generic argument that has to implement the type and then using the generic argument as the type of the function's argument whereas in the second you use the type right on for function's argument.

The best solution to the problem **is to disable the rule**

Edit: If you still want to leave the rule on while keeping your code place your code between `/* tslint:disable:no-unnecessary-generics */` and `/* tslint:enable:no-unnecessary-generics */` comments as they disable the linting inbetween them for the rule specified. More about rule flags of tslint: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/

Comment: I don't have control over that. I made a pull request to the `defenetlyTyped` repo

Comment: @Elias What about the comment I mentioned?

Comment: Ah, right, I don't think I am supposed to do this? This is my first time commiting to an external library

Comment: @Elias either that or remove generic argument from the interface, there are no other options

Comment: Signatures like this are fundamentally incorrect, which is why the rule exists. A function with such a signature cannot possibly be implemented correctly. The correct return type for a function that might return anything is `unknown`, and the consumer of the function must test or assert the type of the return value to narrow it safely. On DefinitelyTyped, PRs that disable or ignore that rule will be rejected.